# Navigation Drawer xith Linear Layout Fail

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

First, sorry for my bad english.

In my application I want to have a Navigation Drawer on the left. It works fine if I do it with a single ListView. Now I want to do it on a Linear Layout. But it don't works.

In facts, the linearLayout is displayed at the beginning and I can't hide it with sliding or home button or item on the list. When I touch an Item or Home button, the application crash.

I give you my code.

activity_main.xml:

```
 <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@color/grisFond">

        [ ... ]

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_above="@+id/Player"
            android:id="@+id/container">

        </FrameLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/lin"
    android:gravity="left">
    <ListView android:id="@+id/my_drawer"
        android:layout_width="248dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:background="@color/fondMenu"/>
</LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

I Precise that DrawerLayout is the root, and it has 2 children. The first child is the frameLayout who contains my fragments and the second one is my navigation drawer

Now My MainActivity.java file:

```
package org.witixradio.app;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.io.IOException;


public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    /**
     *  Déclaration des variables de classe
     */

    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout; 
    private LinearLayout monLayout;
    private String[] drawerItemsList;
    private ListView myDrawer; 
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle actionToggle; 
    private final fragmenttest fragtest = new fragmenttest(); 
    private final FragmentAccueil fragaccueil = new FragmentAccueil(); 

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);// Récupère les données sauvées en cas d'actualisation de l'activité
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar(); //Récupération de la barre d'action
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); // Activation du retour arrière quand clic sur fleche
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true); // Activation du bouton
        actionBar.setLogo(R.drawable.menu_expander); // Affichage de l'icone
        actionBar.setTitle("ACCUEIL"); // Affichage du texte

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        monLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lin);


        actionToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.drawable.arrowaction, R.string.accueil, R.string.accueil) {


            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(view);
                getActionBar().setTitle(R.string.accueil);
            }


            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                getActionBar().setTitle(R.string.accueil);
            }

        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(actionToggle);

        drawerItemsList = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.items);
        myDrawer = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.my_drawer);
        myDrawer.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.drawer_item, drawerItemsList));


        myDrawer.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            showFragment(fragaccueil);
        }

    }


    /**
     * Methode de l'activité
     */

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        actionToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        actionToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (actionToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }



    private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            selectItem(position);

        }
    }

    private void selectItem(int position) {
        if(position==0){
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(monLayout);
        }
        else if(position==1){
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(monLayout);
        }

    }
```

And my error when I touch an Item or the Home button:

```
> 04-24 12:00:53.998  32499-32499/org.witixradio.app E/AndroidRuntime﹕
> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>     Process: org.witixradio.app, PID: 32499
>     java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: View android.widget.LinearLayout{42660148 V.E..... .......D 0,0-1080,1557
> #7f0b0007 app:id/lin} is not a sliding drawer
>             at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.closeDrawer(DrawerLayout.java:1059)
>             at org.witixradio.app.MainActivity.selectItem(MainActivity.java:297)
>             at org.witixradio.app.MainActivity.access$100(MainActivity.java:40)
>             at org.witixradio.app.MainActivity$DrawerItemClickListener.onItemClick(MainActivity.java:282)
>             at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:299)
>             at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1113)
>             at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2904)
>             at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3638)
>             at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
>             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
>             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
>             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
>             at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

For information line 297:

mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(monLayout);

Line 282:

selectItem(position);

And the line 40 is the beginning of my class MainActivity.

I home a genius here will have an answer for me.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the exact same problem as you, finally figured it out by searching GitHub XML files.

[This](https://github.com/UweTrottmann/SeriesGuide) was the project that finally got me to my solution. (see activity_episodes and drawer_left in their layout folder)

They separated out the drawer layout XML into a separate layout file and used `<include` to reference it in their DrawerLayout XML. Doing this, and ensuring that my drawer's layout file was wrapped with `<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> ... </merge>` finally solved it for me, though I can't say for certain why the merge tag is necessary.